# If textbox is empty not working

Tags: javascript

Don't know what im doing wrong, but im if destination is empty it should bring an alert and if submitted should not.

but cant seem to find out what the problem is

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckFormPrac(form){

        var pcheck = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        pattern = /^^02\d{8}$/;

        if (!pattern.test(pcheck))  {
            alert("Please input your number in format of 02########.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        var cdest = document.getElementById("dest").value;
        if (cdest == ""){
            alert("Destination has not been filled.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="ffform" method="get" action=""
Onsubmit="return CheckFormPrac(this);" >
<fieldset>
         Home Phone:
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size=15 onblur="CheckFormPrac(this);" /> <br/>

    What is your favorite destination to fly to?
    <input type="text" name="dest" id="dest" size=30 onblur="CheckFormPrac(this);"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code that checks for the value of `#dest` is never reached.

```
if(!pattern.test(pcheck)) {
    alert("Please input your number in format of 02########.");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

will always return the control from the function and the following code will not be executed. Remove the `else` block from this and the code will check for `#dest` value.

Note that there is no need of `return true;` from the event handler as it is default action of the form.

Here's complete code with some changes:

```
function CheckFormPrac() {
    var pcheck = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    if(!/^02\d{8}$/.test(pcheck)) {
        alert("Please input your number in format of 02########.");
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("dest").value.trim() === "") {
        alert("Destination has not been filled.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've removed both the return true; as you said it is the default action of the event handler.  :) And it worked after I put id="dest" in the input :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your form and also how you are calling your `onsubmit`. Also, you can do this (minus the alerts) without javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/uoLrsz78/

```
<form method="get" action="/">
  Home Phone:
  <input type="text" name="phone" pattern='(02)[0-9]{8}' required/> <br/>

  What is your favorite destination to fly to?
  <input type="text" name="dest" required/> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```